# Apache2 not serving css file with correct file type

Tags: apache2, mime-types

I have a css file

```
https://assess.discipleshipdynamics.com/vendor/log-viewer/app.css?id=93151d8b186ef7758df8582425ff8082
```

that apache is **serving as text/html not text/css.**

On the very same server in a different folder I have

```
https://assess.discipleshipdynamics.com/filament/assets/app.css?id=ceb9a486dfc44ebe8adaa3bd510821e8
```

which is **serving correctly** as text/css.

I have no clue why this is happening. Because it is served as text/html, the browser does not apply any of the css rules to the page in question.

How can I debug this issue?